# non-faithful representation of permutation group?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory

Is there any non-faithful, non-trivial representation of a permutation group? If there are, could you name some examples? I am wondering if there are especially 1-dimensional representations using modulo based on even and odd permutations etc.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but what's wrong with $q:S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ given by the parity of the permutation? I ask because you seem to be aware of this already.

Comment: Since every group is isomorphic to a permutation group, you are just asking whether non-faithful non-trivial representations of groups exist at all. (But perhaps you are using a different definition of permutation group from me?)